# Java, выборка элемента.

Tags: checkbox, awt, java

Собственно сам вопрос звучит довольно глупо. Но я его всё таки задам, так как не смог ничего нагуглить.

Изучаю java и пошёл в сторону awt. Всё вроде было хорошо до того момента, как мне нужно определить состояние чекбокса. Навешиваю лисенер на клик мыши.

```
checkbox.addMouseListener(new DoActiveListener(user_id, checkbox.getState()));
```

Ну и естественно он всегда false. Так как состояние на момент навешивания не чекнутое. Вот вопрос, в обработчике события нужно обратиться к чекбоку (желательно по имени) и сделать ему getState();

Comment: Извините, а где вопрос собственно?

Comment: вопрос - зачем? зачем делать  getState(); в обработчике?

Comment: Ну тогда подскажите другме варианты.

Comment: а что ты хочешь сделать? передавай true

Comment: @Gorets, оригинально :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм, а почему ты не юзаешь `Swing`? `AWT` уже устаревшая считается...
И зачем ты вешаешь `MouseListener`? Вешай на чекбокс `ActionListener`, он будет срабатывать при изменении состояния чекбокса, а в нём уже вызовешь метод `isSelected`. Пример можешь посмотреть: 
* [checkbox listener](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/awt/event/checkbox-listener-example/)